# enabling only the default selected item in dropdown menu in angular and typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

In home page i have login selecting one state. But in other part of a form  where i have to select state again. Here I want the default one that I have selected in home page to show not other available option in menu .Other options in dropdown menu should be disabled.Tried many suggest nothing worked for me.

angular and typescript

```
<ng-select [(ngModel)]="state" (change)="onSelectState()">
<ng-option value="KARNATAKA">KARNATAKA</ng-option>
<ng-option  value="TAMIL NADU" [disabled]="selectedState !== 'TAMIL NADU'" >TAMIL NADU</ng-option>
<ng-option value="ANDHRA PRADESH" [disabled]="selectedState !== 'ANDHRA PRADESH'" >ANDHRA PRADESH</ng-option>
                        </ng-select>



.ts
onSelectState() {
 this.getAllVillage('districts', this.state, 'district', 'StateName', 'Districtname');
    }

tried working with this not working.
```

Comment: Hi sunitha, and welcome to StackOverflow! This is maybe your first question, so I would like to draw your attention to the [How-to-ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Following it will make it much more likely that you receive helpful answers.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

your question is asked rather odd. I would suggest editing your question so we can have a better look at the problem. The only tip i can give you is attribute selected on your option element, which makes it selected by default.

`<ng-option value="valueX" selected>valueX</ng-option>`